# How do I start start an specific app Maximized?

Tags: gnome, window

By example, Discord is starting in a minimized window, but I want it to start like for example Firefox does by default, completely maximized window. There's no way to change this in the GUI of the app, so I'm looking for a method on Ubuntu to get what I want.

Thanks for your help.